# Salesforce Account Creation via REST POST API Is Always Failing With Error "Bad Request" Via C#

Tags: c#, salesforce, http-post, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to write a simple console based application with the help from C# to create Salesforce standard objects like Accounts, Contacts, Leads etc. As a starting point I tried to create account using following code but it is always failing with below reason.

**Code Snippet -**

```
            // Here string requestbody = "{\"name\":\"Testrun Limited\", \"city\":\"Delhi\"}"
            public static string SFPostCall2(string requestbody)
            {
                string responseresult = string.Empty;

                using ( var client = new HttpClient())
                {   
                    // Headers
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", SalesforceClient.AuthToken);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");

                    // Contents 
                    Uri URL = new Uri("https://mysalesforce-env.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/account");
                    var data = new StringContent(requestbody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = client.PostAsync(URL, data).Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    responseresult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                }

                return responseresult;
            }
```

**Error Details -**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not
indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).'
```

Response Body -

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2022 12:08:46 GMT
  Set-Cookie: CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 12:08:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
  Set-Cookie: LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 12:08:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
  Set-Cookie: BrowserId=OfVYGvekEeyahU8Wnegiow; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 12:08:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Robots-Tag: none
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0, private
  Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=16/15000
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
}
```

**Please Note :-**

1. I have successfully got the Salesforce Token while using the GET request.
2. Same request with same parameters in POSTMAN is creating data successfully every time
3. I have also tried using
   `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls` but still no
   help
4. Same request via `JavaScript` is also creating data from IE browser { to avoid CORS error }.
5. I have also tried to change the content to `JSON` object using following code, but still got same error -

```
    var dataobj = new
     {
       Name = "Testrun Limited",
       City = "Delhi"
     };
     
    var jsondataobj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataobj);
    HttpContent c_content = new StringContent(jsondataobj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: 400 is a response code from the server. It's not a TLS version issue. Presumably something is wrong with your request, so you should check what is sent back in the response body as that will give you a good hint.

Comment: Hi @DiplomacyNotWar, Thanks for your input. I have included the Response body in the question. This is what present inside var response variable.

Comment: The response body would be the result of `responseresult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. That doesn't seem to be what you've included in your question.

Comment: a) We can't really see the body in your question b) I found that HTTP2 sometimes called JSON to be abruptly terminated between SF and my client. So I had to set HTTP to 1.1 like so `myRequest.Version = new Version(1, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

This style worked for me.

```
 HttpRequestMessage requestUpdate = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
 requestUpdate.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + SFAuthToken);  
 requestUpdate.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 requestUpdate.Content = contentUpdate;
  
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();      
 HttpResponseMessage asyncResponse = client.SendAsync(requestUpdate).Result;
 var content = asyncResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```